# Accessing of file in remote server using php showing error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to make an ecommerce website. Vendors can add images and details of their products. On selecting an image it will upload to remote machine successfully by using ajax and js. When the vendor submitting the details about the product it will added to the database after compressing of the uploaded image. Backend is completely with php & mysql. When submitting the the product details it showing an error 500. Is it because of file permissions or any other error?

Comment: That doesn't really mean anything. You need to either enable error reporting or check the log files.

Comment: it is php error. show php logs. to try go to Backend path simply by browser to test routing. to checking permissions to try creacing the folder into saving path from current user who running php.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the log files and found the exact problem. I am using imagecreatefromjpeg() function. The error shown that function is undefined. So I installed GD library. Now everything working fine.